# Slicing in Python Creates A Copy of What Type?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to understand how slicing in Python works. I have read that slice objects utilizes **getitem** and **len** methods. I will ask my question with a code:

```
l = [[0],[1]]
l[0:1][0] = [99]
The result of these lines are 
>> l -> [[0],[1]]
```

However,

```
l = [[0],[1]]
l[0:1][0].append(1)
The result of these lines are 
>> l -> [[0, 1], [1]]
```

I have no idea whats going on. Is this a shallow copy? If so why hasnt the list changed after assigment operator but with append method... Could someone clearly explain it to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you pointed out, slicing creates a shallow copy.
In the first example you created a copy of the `l` list and replaced its first item. The original list remains untouched.

In the second example you created a copy of the `l` list and altered its first item. Because the copy was shallow both `l` and the copy of `l` have a reference to the same `[0]` list as their first item. You appended 1 to it, so it's reflected by both the original list `l` and its copy.

Comment: Nicely explained.  Just what I was about to say ;-).

Comment: if I created a shallow copy, shouldnt the result in the first example also change?

Comment: In the first example you only replaced what the list stores at index 0. So the there's a different reference there now (that points to `[99]`). You don't modify the underlying object (list `[0]`).

Comment: Ohhh alright I get it now If anyone is confused use this image to understand whats going on and thanks!! https://cdncontribute.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/shallow-copy.jpg